# Реализация запроса к базе данных с множественным условием where

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать запрос к БД через PHP?

Допустим, имеется БД *planets*, и в ней столбцы такого типа:

- name: земля, меркурий, венера...
- размер: big, small, large
- температура: hot, cold

Все эти данные приходят с формы, и запрос:

```
Select * from Planet where размер = 'big' AND темепратура = 'hot'
```

Но, бывает такое, что в форме пропускают один из параметров намерено, дабы получить результат только по одному критерию:

```
Select * from Planet where размер = 'big' AND темепратура = ''
```

А если таких критериев (столбцов) будет больше, то как это реализовать на PHP?

```php
if ($_POST['size'] = '') {
  $sql = "Select * from planet where температура = $_POST['temperatura']";
} else {
  "Select * from planet where размер = 'big' AND температура = $_POST['temperatura']"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Суть примера кода ниже в том, чтобы показать, что такую задачу можно решить, собирая SQL-запрос согласно данным, которые поступают на сервер.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `planet` WHERE 1'; //Объявляем переменную, содержащую по умолчанию строку с SQL-запросом, выбирающим все строки из таблицы (не БД, а таблицы) planet
$whereAND = ''; //Объявляем пустую строку, содержащую дополнительные условия AND для SQL-запроса.

//Если пользователь указал, что хочет выбрать планеты по размеру (если в массиве $_POST содержится элемент с ключом size)
if (isset($_POST['size'])) {
    $whereAND .= ' AND `size` = ' . $_POST['size']; //Добавляем в строку дополнительных условий условие выборки по размеру планеты
}

if (isset($_POST['temperature'])) {
    $whereAND .= ' AND `temperature` = ' . $_POST['temperature'];
}
//и т.д.

$sql .= $sql . $whereAND;
```

P.S. Много `if` или же `switch` - выбирать Вам. Также стоит задуматься о безопасности SQL-запросов (не уверен, что у вас реальный проект, но безопасности место всегда найдётся).

Comment: Я мимо проходил и не разбираюсь в пхп, но увидел как у вас запрос строится и возник вопрос: этот код не сломается при попытке sql инъекции?

Comment: @tym32167 Сломается. Точнее SQL-инъекция пройдёт без каких-либо проблем. Лишь постарался напрямую дать ответ автору вопроса, показав, как можно построить запрос, если будет несколько полей. Уже писать о том, как сделать его безопасным (хоть использовать тот же PDO для предопределённых запросов с параметризацией) не стал.

Comment: ага, я понял. Ну, защита от SQL инъекций не входит в вопрос, но, я думаю, это полезное замечание для будущих читателей, что в прод этот код как есть не стоит брать, надо дополнительно озаботиться защитой от SQL инъекций.

Answer (score -1):

Сначала опишите все параметры которые ожидают получить. Например, эти

```
$params = ['size', 'temperature', ];
```

Потом собираем то что реально пришло

```
$values = [];
foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (array_key_exists($param, $_POST)) {
        $values[] = $param . ' = ' . $_POST[$param];
    }
}
```

Дополнительно, собранные значения можно "почистить"

```
$values = array_filter($values); // или с $callback где можно проверить значение
```

Далее собираем запрос

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `planet` ' . implode(' and ' , $values);
```

ps. Как указано, не забывайте про инъекции и используйте подстановки!